# Can't consistently ping both networks of multihomed host

Tags: networking, routing, interface, multi-homed

I have a host which is multihomed, eth0 is on 172.31.254.0/24 and eth0.10 is on 172.31.253.0/24 .  Obviously eth0.10 is a subinterface on vlan id 10.

From this host I can succesfully ping hosts on the 172.31.253.0/24 network but not **consistently** on the 172.31.254.0/24 network.  For example, notice the dropout in pings #5-#25:

```
[root@pbx1 ~]# ping -I eth0 172.31.254.37                      
PING 172.31.254.31 (172.31.254.31) from 172.31.254.13 eth0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.31.254.37: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=1.03 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.254.37: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.247 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.254.37: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=0.236 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.254.37: icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=4.00 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.254.37: icmp_seq=26 ttl=128 time=0.237 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.254.37: icmp_seq=27 ttl=128 time=0.299 ms
```

My interfaces look right:

```
[root@myhost1 ~]# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:4D:B2:28:AC  
          inet addr:172.31.254.13  Bcast:172.31.254.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::222:4dff:feb2:28ac/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:121808 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:120948 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:16685937 (15.9 MiB)  TX bytes:23059300 (21.9 MiB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:d0020000-d0040000 

eth0.10 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:4D:B2:28:AC  
          inet addr:172.31.253.4  Bcast:172.31.253.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::222:4dff:feb2:28ac/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2732 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:828 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1394817 (1.3 MiB)  TX bytes:417925 (408.1 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:30573 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:30573 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2225449 (2.1 MiB)  TX bytes:2225449 (2.1 MiB)
```

and the routing table looks right:

```
[root@myhost1 ~]# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
172.31.254.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
172.31.253.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0.10
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
default         firewall.mydomain.com 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

So why are my packets not getting to (or responses getting back from) hosts on the 172.31.254.0/24 network?  I set /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/rp_filter to 0 but it makes no difference

---

Update: Routing table for destination host:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     172.31.254.1    172.31.254.37    266
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
     172.31.252.0    255.255.255.0     172.31.254.2    172.31.254.37     11
     172.31.253.0    255.255.255.0     172.31.254.2    172.31.254.37     11
     172.31.254.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     172.31.254.37    266
    172.31.254.37  255.255.255.255         On-link     172.31.254.37    266
   172.31.254.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     172.31.254.37    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     172.31.254.37    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     172.31.254.37    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
     172.31.252.0    255.255.255.0     172.31.254.2       1
     172.31.253.0    255.255.255.0     172.31.254.2       1
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     172.31.254.1  Default
===========================================================================
```

Comment: Does your switch support VLAN tagging, and is it configured correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You may have 172.31.254.13 used twice on your network.

I am also suspecting routing or arp issues on the receiving side:

Could you check *arp -na* on host 172.31.254.13 and host 172.31.254.31 ?

Full routing tables with *ip route* command on each host might also help.

Comment: I confirmed there are no duplicate addresses (.13 or .31).  The routing table for the source is already above, and I've added the routing table for the destination (a windows machine).

Answer (score 0):

I needed to create an iproute2 policy, and the disable rp_filter for the interface and subinterface.

After that it worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

You are having a VIP on a different network on the same card. (same MAC)
Try to do the same but create vNIC that are separate segments and then set a default route and specific for the other NIC.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  The default route is already eth0 (the same subnet that I can't ping consistantly). Are you saying I should set a default route for each NIC? (I don't think that's possible)

Comment: There is only one default route. You can have routes for specific networks defined for each network. How did you create two different subnets on the same NIC? I never seen that.

Comment: Add a subinterface to a NIC to get the 2 subnets